# Calling code of Button from another one in C#

Tags: c#, .net, button, click, action

I need to know if it's possible to call the Click of a button from another one.

```
private void myAction_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // int x;
    // ...
}

private void Go_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // call the myAction_Click button
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is the reason to make another button click?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want:

```
private void Go_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myAction_Click(sender, e);
}
```

---

But a better design is to pull the code out:

```
private void myAction_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DoSomething();
}

private void Go_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DoSomething();
}

private void DoSomething()
{
    // Your code here
}
```

Comment: Thanks man it worked, I think I will put the code in another function an call here in both Buttons.

Answer (score 0):

The button has a PerformClick method.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hkkb40tf(v=vs.90).aspx