# Passing variable from one button click to another

Tags: c#, winforms, button, buttonclick

This is a simple question but I can't seem to find an answer.  I want to use the stored value from one button click to another within the same form. Any assistance would greatly be appreciated.  I tried using an example from [Calling code of Button from another one in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5985378/calling-code-of-button-from-another-one-in-c-sharp) but could not get it to work.

```
public struct xmlData
    {
         public string xmlAttribute;   
    }

private void Show_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
           xmlData myXML = new xmlData();
                //do something.....
           myXML.xmlAttributes = "blah"
    }

private void Submit_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
 //I want to call myXML.xmlAttributes retrieving the stored value from Show_btn_Click
    }
```

Comment: That should be a class, not a struct.

Comment: thank you for the quick responses! Valin's solution worked best for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should declare myXML variable at higher level of scope.

```
xmlData myXML = new xmlData();

public struct xmlData
{
     public string xmlAttribute;   
}

private void Show_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            //do something.....
       myXML.xmlAttributes = "blah"
}

private void Submit_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 //I want to call myXML.xmlAttributes retrieving the stored value from Show_btn_Click
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instanciate the xmlData in the Constructor so you can access it overall in the class.

```
public class XYZ
{    
   xmlData myXML; 

   public XYZ()
   {
       myXML = new xmlData();
   }

   private void Show_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {            
       //do something.....
       myXML.xmlAttributes = "blah"
   }

   private void Submit_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      // Here you can work myXML.xmlAttributes
   }    
}
```